# JQuery-UI Autocomplete passing additional parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, autocomplete

I have a Textbox and Autocomplete. If the user types in the Autocomplete it filters the results and display the desired result and its all good but I want to extend it pass another parameters to the Autocomplete how would I do that?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
```

I know that JQuery-UI use 'term' for filter data.

here is my autocomplete.

```
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location)
     @(Html.JQueryUI().AutocompleteFor(model => model.LocationId,  
              Url.Action((LocationsController c) => c.JsonSearch(null,model.EmployeeName)), 
              Html.IdFor(model => model.Location).ToString(), 
              Model.Location).MinLength(3).Delay(400))
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult JsonSearch(string term, string employeeName)
    {  
        //i see the employeeName as null here...

        //var results {....more code....}
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case I wanted to pass the Employee Name that user enters

hope this will help others :)

```
$("#location").on("autocompletesearch", function (event, ui) {
      var empName = $("#EmployeeName").val(); //passing employee name
      var url = "@(Url.Action((LocationsController c) => c.JsonSearch(null,null)))";
      if(empName) {
         url += "?empname = " + empName;
      }
      $(this).autocomplete("option", "source", url);
});
```